# Http package refused connection on mobile network many time but on wifi works fine after updating http package

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, flutter-http

My whole team face this problem in our retailer app API works slowly on mobile network but on Wi-Fi works superb. It is not API problem http package have some kind of issue. please help to rectify this problem as much as possible.

### Output:-

> E/flutter (25854): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
> Unhandled Exception: Connection refused E/flutter (25854): #0
> IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:88:7) E/flutter
> (25854):  E/flutter (25854): #1 BaseClient._sendUnstreamed
> (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32) E/flutter (25854):
> E/flutter (25854): #2 _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:12)
> E/flutter (25854):  E/flutter (25854): #3
> _SuperDistributorScreenState.build..... (package:financepe_master/modules/super_distributor/views/super_distributor_screen.dart:581:69)
> E/flutter (25854):  E/flutter (25854):

my whole team team face this problem in our retailer app api works slowly on mobile network but on wifi works superb. it is not api problem `http` package have some kind of issue. please help to rectify this problem as much as possible.

Comment: have you tried Server api on postman? and have you added internet permission in manifest file?

Comment: Yes I tried all as you say

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't think the problem is from the http package.
The error can possibly be from your code.

But you can also try out this other packages [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio). It works perfectly well and can be a substitute for the **http** package.

Comment: I used that as well and faces same problem

Comment: if code have problems  than on wifi it must have problems but wifi doesn't have connection refused problem but mobile network have

Comment: Okay... I think this might be a mobile network connection issue from the device. Maybe checking it out or troubleshooting could help out..